# Android launch intent from onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Activity onCreate method I create and Intent (say to launch the camera) and call startActivityForResult.  The problem is that onCreate is called twice and the Intent is launched twice.  Both are received in onActivityResult.

What is going on here?  How should I automatically launch an Intent when my Activity loads?  I tried calling startActivityForResult in onStart, but it is still called twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate` is normally called when you return from another activity, like in your example. The activity lifecycle docs by Google are a bit misleading in this respect (they make you think `onCreate` only called once during the app lifecycle).

Your best bet is to save your state in `onSaveInstanceState`, e.g. add a `cameraCalled` flag, and then check that flag in `onCreate` to prevent a loop.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate may and may not be called when you are returning.

It will depend on memory situation and whether or not OS killed your activity.  You will need to account for both scenarios.  It is probably not doable when you call from onCreate.  See this for more information on order of what is called on the return [State of Activity while in onActivityResult question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059028/state-of-activity-while-in-onactivityresult-question)